# Unable to pull package in GCP Artifact Registry using helm pull ("Unable to locate any tags in provided repository")

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, kubernetes-helm, google-artifact-registry

I am getting the following error when trying to pull a Helm chart using helm pull and helm fetch from my "Docker" GCP Artifact registry repo:

`Error: Unable to locate any tags in provided repository: oci://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/(project)/helm-charts/cicd:1.`

I was able to push the package to the Artifact Registry using

`helm push  cicd-1.tgz oci://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/(project)/helm-charts`

meaning authentication must be working, and I do see the chart in my repo.

GCP shows `docker pull us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/(project)/helm-charts/cicd:1` as the command for Docker (meaning the path should be correct, prefixed with oci://). I've tried different tags. I initially noticed this when trying to apply using Terraform.